# Parse Login Button Bringing User to Next Screen Even When User Error or Incorrect Login Credentials

Tags: objective-c, xcode, authentication, parse-platform

I am using parse.com's backend and this is the code linked to my sign in button. The problem is that even if the user's username/password is wrong or the user doesn't enter one or the other, it will bring the user to the main screen and then it will say the error message.

Any idea why?

Thanks for the help in advance

```
- (IBAction)didTapLogin:(id)sender
{
NSString *username = usernameEntry.text;
NSString *password = passwordEntry.text;

if ((username.length != 4) && (password.length != 4))
{
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Signing in..." Interaction:NO];
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
     {
         if (user != nil)
         {
             [ProgressHUD showSuccess:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome back %@!", [user objectForKey:PF_USER_FULLNAME]]];
              [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
         }
         else [ProgressHUD showError:[error.userInfo valueForKey:@"error"]];
     }];
}
else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Please enter both username and password."];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `if (error == nil)` instead of if user is nil. The user can be non-nil if your app has enabled automatic user.

Comment: I tried changing it to if (error == nil) and it still does the same thing @danh

Comment: Just to be certain, error==nil means the log in succeeds.

Comment: Yes, but changing it still doesn't fix the problem @danh